# "byte" data type containing weird characters

Tags: c++

`byte` defined as `typedef unsigned char byte` under Windows contains weird **extra** information.

```
byte *myByte = new unsigned char[myByteSize]();
myByte[0] = 94;
```

When I print `myByte[0]`, I get 94 as expected but when i put a break point at check the debugger `myByte[0] = 94 '^'`

Why is '^' getting attached to my data?

Comment: It is the ASCII representation of 94 - See http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't *attached* to your data. The debugger shows a number and its ASCII representation (a *character* with the same ASCII code) if possible. The `^` character is the 94th in the ASCII chart.

Comment: There shouldn't be. You did the right thing by answering. Answers belong in the _answer section_.

Comment: Do the honorable thing - I did not think the post required an answer

Comment: @EdHeal: Do the honourable thing and delete your answer-as-comment! (Then don't post any more please)

Comment: @EdHeal, I believe every question requires an answer